# How to Exclude Duplicate C Shared Libraries (.so) in a Multi-Project Android Build?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I get a "duplicate files" conflict when building a parent project with two library modules, which make use of the same `libc++_shared.so` shared library.

(**NOTE**:  Please do not consider this a "duplicate question".  I have read several related posts, which have helped me get this far.  However, no posts have provided an answer that works in my case involving *NDK artifacts*.)

The build was working correctly when I only had 1 such library module.  The addition of the second library module is now creating the conflict.

Consider the following project structure:  1 parent project, 2 "child" projects - but each project is located at the same directory level (i.e.  Not nested hierarchically)

```
ProjectA/   (Parent)
    LibraryModuleA1/
        build/exploded-aar/com.package.name/
            LibraryModuleB1/<version>/jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
            LibraryModuleC1/<version>/jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
        build.gradle    (bgA1)
    Test_APK_Module A1T/
        build.gradle    (bgA1T)
    build.gradle    (bgPA)

ProjectB/
    LibraryModuleB1/  (Uses NDK)
        build/lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
        build.gradle    (bgB1)
    build.gradle    (bgPB)

ProjectC/
    LibraryModuleC1/  (Uses NDK)
        build/lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
        build.gradle    (bgC1)
    build.gradle    (bgPC)
```

Library Module A1 depends on both Library Modules B1 & C1.
A1 -> B1
A1 -> C1

Projects B and C both have NDK-based code and build/test correctly.  Both depend on the `libc++_shared.so` shared library.

However, when building Project A, I get the following error during the `:LibraryModuleA1:packageDebugTest` task:

```
Error: duplicate files during packaging of APK   /ProjectA/LibraryModuleA1/build/apk/LibraryModuleA1-debug-test-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
    Origin 1:  /ProjectA/LibraryModuleA1/build/exploded-aar/com.package.name/LibraryModuleB1/<version>/jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
    Origin 2:  /ProjectA/LibraryModuleA1/build/exploded-aar/com.package.name/LibraryModuleC1/<version>/jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
      }
    }

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':LibraryModuleA1:packageDebugTest'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
    File 1: /ProjectA/LibraryModuleA1/build/exploded-aar/com.package.name/LibraryModuleC1/<version>/jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
    File 2: /ProjectA/LibraryModuleA1/build/exploded-aar/com.package.name/LibraryModuleC1/<version>/jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so

:LibraryModuleA1:packageDebugTest FAILED
```

**What I've Tried So Far**

1. I attempted to add the suggested closure to my `build.gradle` file, but which `build.gradle` file do I add it to?  I have added the closure to `bgA1`, `bgB1`, and `bgC1` (one at a time), with no success.
2. The suggested closure says to use `exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'`.  Each "child" library module builds the `libc++_shared.so` file under the `build/lib` path.  However, I noticed that the parent library module copies the `libc++_shared.so` file under `jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so` inside the `build/exploded-aar` directory structure.  (See above)  Should the closure instead read `exclude 'jni/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so`  (i.e.  `jni` vs. `lib`)?
3. Since I am using Gradle plugin 0.9.1, I tried using `pickFirst` in place of `exclude`, but that wasn't successful either.

Can someone help determine how I should configure the `packagingOptions' closure for my given case?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and had no luck with exclude or pickFirst. So I used a somewhat ugly workaround. The idea is to create a 'native-libs' folder in the build directory of the main project, copy all required *.so files from ndk library projects there and then tell the build system to package those libs in the apk.

In my main project (the app project), I explicitely define the list of modules that contain ndk codes on which I depend

```
// Ndk stuff. We have to explicitely manage our NDK dependencies
ext.jniProjects = [project(':ndklib1'), project(':ndklib2'), project(':ndklib3')]
apply from: '../depend_ndk.gradle'
```

And then, 'depend_ndk.gradle' is a gradle external script that contains

```
// Build helper for projects that depends on a native library with a NDK part
// Define the list of ndk library you depend on in project main file :
//   ext.jniProjects = [project(':ndklib1')]
//   apply from : 'depend_ndk.gradle'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
import com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication

// As a workaround, we create a new 'native-libs' folder in the current project and
// copy all the .so we depend on into it
def ndkLibsDir = new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
ndkLibsDir.mkdir()

task copyDependingNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    // Doc for copy http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html
    println 'jniProjects ' + jniProjects
    jniProjects.each {
        from(new File(it.buildDir, 'native-libs')) {
            include '**/*.so'
        }
    }
    into ndkLibsDir
}

tasks.withType(PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(ndkLibsDir)
    pkgTask.dependsOn copyDependingNativeLibs
}
```

Comment: How does the PackageApplication get triggered? in the App - I'm not seeing it on debug builds... so my debug APK's are including... Thanks.

Comment: You're right, I'm having troubles getting copyDependingNativeLibs to run automatically. I think adding it as a dependency for pkgTask is not the right thing to do. I haven't really had the time to find a solution, so for now I just run './gradlew app:copyDependingNativeLibs' when I change some native part.