# Android gradle duplicate native shared libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My question is similar to the one asked here:

[How to Exclude Duplicate C Shared Libraries (.so) in a Multi-Project Android Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314983/how-to-exclude-duplicate-c-shared-libraries-so-in-a-multi-project-android-bui)

In my project, I have a shared library which has some native code `MySharedLib` . I have an app `TestDuplicateSharedLibApp` which depends on `MySharedLib` and also has native code.

As part of the gradle build, I disable automatic call to `ndk-build` by setting `jni.srcDirs =[]`. I explicitly call ndk-build command.

As part of the `MySharedLib` build process, `libMySharedLib.so` is generaed and packaged in to `MySharedLib.aar`.

`TestDuplicateSharedLibApp` depends on `MySharedLib`. As part of the ndk-build, `libTestDuplicateSharedLibApp.so` and `libMySharedLib.so` are copied to the `TestDuplicateSharedLibApp/libs` directory.

Since I need to package shared libraries in the final apk, I have `jniLibs.srcDirs=['libs']` in my build.gradle.

When the final apk is being packaged, the packaging fails due to duplicate copies of `libMyShared.so` , one from `MySharedLib.aar` and other from `TestDuplicateSharedLibApp/libs` . I tried `pick-first` and `exclude` packaging options, but they didn't help.

Basically what I need is an equivalent of `jniLibs.srcDirs` for files. In `TestDuplicateSharedLibApp` I would like to say: Only include `libTestDuplicateSharedLibApp.so`. I envision this by doing: `jniLibs.srcDirs=[]` and, if there exists a `jniLibs.srcFiles` option `jniLibs.srcFiles='libTestDuplicateSharedLibApp.so'`

I would appreciate insights in solving this problem.

Comment: So how did you solve it? This post is almost a year old, do you have a solution now?